mat-form-field is not a known element
I have upgraded an app to Angular 17 (from 12). However, I am getting many runtime errors related to the Material modules. I've tried many things in an attempt to get it fixed, but can't figure out what the problem is.
Error: src/app/pages/table-maintenance/maintain-invalid-tax-id/modal/maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal.component.html:5:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:

If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal.component.html:
<h2 mat-dialog-title>ADR Foreign Tax Reclaims: {{description}} TaxIds</h2>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <form [formGroup]="invalidTaxIdsForm">
    <div fxLayout fxLayoutGap="20px">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label class="bold">Invalid Tax ID</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text"  placeholder="Invalid Tax ID" maxlength="10" cdkFocusInitial formControlName="invalidTaxId" />
        <mat-error *ngIf="invalidTaxIdsForm.controls.invalidTaxId.touched && invalidTaxIdsForm.controls.invalidTaxId?.errors">
          Tax id must be entered.
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div fxLayout fxLayoutGap="20px">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label class="bold">Comment</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" maxlength="255"  placeholder="Comment" formControlName="comment" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

  <div>
      <mat-label class="bold mat-red">{{errorMsg}}</mat-label>
    </div> 
    
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px">
    <button fxFlex="25" mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="isAdd (click)="addNew()">Submit</button>
     <button fxFlex="25" mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="isEdit" (click)="updateInvalidTaxIds()">Submit</button>
    <button fxFlex="25" mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div> 

maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal.component.ts:
import { Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder, UntypedFormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AppConstants } from '@app/shared/models/app-constants';
import { MaintainInvalidTaxIdsModel } from '../models/maintain-invalid-taxId.model';
import { MaintainInvalidTaxIdService } from '../services/maintain-invalid-tax-id.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal',
  templateUrl: './maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./maintain-invalid-tax-id-modal.component.scss']
})
export class MaintainInvalidTaxIdModalComponent implements OnInit {
  invalidTaxIdsForm: UntypedFormGroup;
  description: string;
  action: string;
  errorMsg: string;
  isEdit: boolean = false;
  isAdd: boolean = false;


  constructor(private formBuilder: UntypedFormBuilder,
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    private service:MaintainInvalidTaxIdService ,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MaintainInvalidTaxIdModalComponent>,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: MaintainInvalidTaxIdsModel) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.actionInitializer();
    this.createForm();

    if (this.isEdit) {
      this.patchEditForm();
      this.invalidTaxIdsForm.controls['invalidTaxId'].disable();

    }
  }
//[Code removed for brevity]
}

app.module.ts:
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './pages/logout/logout.component';
import { appInitializer } from './app.initializer';
import { environment } from '@environments/environment';


//Modules
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MaterialModule } from './material-module';
import { ControlsModule } from 'src/app/controls/controls.module';
import { SharedComponentsModule } from './shared/components/shared-components.module';
import { NgIdleModule } from '@ng-idle/core';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

//Interceptors
import { JwtInterceptor } from 'src/app/shared/interceptors/jwt/jwt.interceptor';
import { LoadingSpinnerInterceptor } from './shared/interceptors/loading-spinner/loading-spinner.interceptor';
import { ServiceUnavailableInterceptor } from './shared/interceptors/status-code/service-unavailable.interceptor';
import { Status401Interceptor } from 'src/app/shared/interceptors/status-code/status-401.interceptor';
import { Status404Interceptor } from 'src/app/shared/interceptors/status-code/status-404.interceptor';
import { Status405Interceptor } from './shared/interceptors/status-code/status-405.interceptor';
import { Status500Interceptor } from 'src/app/shared/interceptors/status-code/status-500.interceptor';

//Layout
import { HeaderComponent } from 'src/app/shared/layout/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from 'src/app/shared/layout/footer/footer.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from 'src/app/shared/layout/nav-menu/nav-menu.component';

//Services
import { ConfigurationService } from './shared/services/configuration/configuration.service';
import { ENVIRONMENT } from './shared/services/configuration/environment-token';
import { AuthenticationService } from "@app/shared/services/authentication/authentication.service";
import { LoggingService } from '@app/shared/services/logging/logging.service';
import { LogPublisherService } from '@app/shared/services/logging/log-publisher.service';

export function initConfiguration(configService: ConfigurationService) {
  return () => configService.loadApiConfig();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    ControlsModule,
    SharedComponentsModule,
    NgIdleModule.forRoot(),
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ENVIRONMENT, useValue: environment },
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initConfiguration,
      multi: true,
      deps: [ConfigurationService]
    },
    LoadingSpinnerInterceptor,
    LoggingService,
    LogPublisherService,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: appInitializer, multi: true, deps: [AuthenticationService] },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: LoadingSpinnerInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Status500Interceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Status404Interceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Status405Interceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: Status401Interceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ServiceUnavailableInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

What I did:
Added MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule to app.module.ts as suggested in previous post.
Verified that Material is successfully installed (@angular/material@17.3.6).
I appreciate any help.

Your component MaintainInvalidTaxIdModalComponent doesn't appear to be standalone and also isn't declared in your app.module.ts. This probably means it's declared in a different module.
You need to import MatFormFieldModule and MatInputModule in the same module that declares the component you're trying to use them in.

I thought app.module.ts is global and is accessible to all components?

"Your component MaintainInvalidTaxIdModalComponent doesn't appear to be standalone and also isn't declared in your app.module.ts. This probably means it's declared in a different module." - This fixed it. Thank you!

@ScottMichael I thought app.module.ts is global and is accessible to all components? Nope it's just the root-level module for your app, but if you're using other modules then each module must import the relevant modules for the components it declares. You do have an import of something .forRoot() which would provide it to your whole app as a singleton without needing to "redeclare" it in each of your child modules.
